# Python Move a File from Remote Machine to Local

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

I am new in python and trying different stuff.

Currently trying to copy a text file `to_copy.txt` from a remote machine with local ip `192.168.1.101` to my current machine.

What i tried from googling does not seem to work.

```
import paramiko
from scp import SCPClient

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("testme@192.168.1.101", password="look420")
print("Connected")
scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
scp.get("/home/testme/target_folder/to_copy.txt")
scp.close()
```

But, when i run this i get error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uc/Python_Projects/MoveFileAndFolder/move_remote.py", line 7, in <module>
    ssh.connect("testme@192.168.1.101", password="look420")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 296, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 200, in _families_and_addresses
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

What i am doing wrong here?

**NOTE:** Current machine is running `Debian Jessie` and the remote machine runs `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS`

Comment: Try `ssh.connect("192.168.1.101", username="testme", password="look420")`

Comment: Wow!, that works!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
ssh.connect("192.168.1.101", username="testme", password="look420")
```

Please refer [Doc](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/client.html)

Comment: If you have some time, can you please tell me why it was so? arn't they both same things?

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083132/paramiko-and-python-ssh

Answer (score 1):

The port for scp (22) is likely not open on the remote machine. Please check with a command line call to confirm that you can indeed make an ssh or scp connection.

See here for more details

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles

Answer (score 0):

Download file resources from a remote server to a local through paramiko

```py
import paramiko
import os
from stat import S_ISDIR as isdir


def down_from_remote(sftp_obj, remote_dir_name, local_dir_name):
    "" "download files remotely" ""
    remote_file = sftp_obj.stat(remote_dir_name)
    if isdir(remote_file.st_mode):
        # Folder, can't download directly, need to continue cycling
        check_local_dir(local_dir_name)
        print('Start downloading folder: ' + remote_dir_name)

        for remote_file_name in sftp.listdir(remote_dir_name):
            sub_remote = os.path.join(remote_dir_name, remote_file_name)
            sub_remote = sub_remote.replace('\\', '/')
            sub_local = os.path.join(local_dir_name, remote_file_name)
            sub_local = sub_local.replace('\\', '/')
            down_from_remote(sftp_obj, sub_remote, sub_local)
    else:
        # Files, downloading directly
        print('Start downloading file: ' + remote_dir_name)
        sftp.get(remote_dir_name, local_dir_name)


def check_local_dir(local_dir_name):
    "" "whether the local folder exists, create if it does not exist" ""
    if not os.path.exists(local_dir_name):
        os.makedirs(local_dir_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    "" "program main entry" ""
    # Server connection information
    host_name = 'ipaddress'
    user_name = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    port = 22
    # Remote file path (absolute path required)
    remote_dir = '/data/nfs/zdlh/pdf/2018/07/31'
    # Local file storage path (either absolute or relative)
    local_dir = 'file_download/'

    # Connect to remote server
    t = paramiko.Transport((host_name, port))
    t.connect(username=user_name, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)

    # Remote file start download
    down_from_remote(sftp, remote_dir, local_dir)

    # Close connection
    t.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

""
Download file resources from remote server to local through paramiko
author: gxcuizy
time: 2018-08-01
"""

import paramiko
import os
from stat import S_ISDIR as isdir

def down_from_remote(sftp_obj, remote_dir_name, local_dir_name):
"" "download files remotely" ""
remote_file = sftp_obj.stat(remote_dir_name)
if isdir(remote_file.st_mode):
# Folder, can't download directly, need to continue cycling
check_local_dir(local_dir_name)
print('Start downloading folder: ' + remote_dir_name)

```
    for remote_file_name in sftp.listdir(remote_dir_name):
        sub_remote = os.path.join(remote_dir_name, remote_file_name)
        sub_remote = sub_remote.replace('\\', '/')
        sub_local = os.path.join(local_dir_name, remote_file_name)
        sub_local = sub_local.replace('\\', '/')
        down_from_remote(sftp_obj, sub_remote, sub_local)
else:
    # Files, downloading directly
    print('Start downloading file: ' + remote_dir_name)
    sftp.get(remote_dir_name, local_dir_name)
```

def check_local_dir(local_dir_name):
"" "whether the local folder exists, create if it does not exist" ""
if not os.path.exists(local_dir_name):
os.makedirs(local_dir_name)

if **name** == "**main**":
"" "program main entry" ""
# Server connection information
host_name = 'ip'
user_name = 'name'
password = 'pwd'
port = 22
# Remote file path (absolute path required)
remote_dir = '/data/nfs/zdlh/pdf/2018/07/31'
# Local file storage path (either absolute or relative)
local_dir = 'file_download/'

```
# Connect to remote server
t = paramiko.Transport((host_name, port))
t.connect(username=user_name, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)

# Remote file start download
down_from_remote(sftp, remote_dir, local_dir)

# Close connection
t.close()
```

Comment: Please add a short description on what your code is doing. And how.